# Error: 404 link doesn't begin with `base` - While building for GitHub Pages with Sveltekit

Tags: git, github, svelte, sveltekit

I had a problem which [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/11wcej3/error_404_link_doesnt_begin_with_base_while/) had mentioned, so I added `{base}` to all the links. I'm sure I modified the links correctly. After that I got a new error:`/tbilisi-1.webp does not begin with 'base'`

Thing is, I generate posts for my website using `{#each}` and the links for the images of the posts are received from an array `['tbilisi-1.webp', 'tbilisi-2.webp', 'tbilisi-3.webp']...` (This probably is not be a good way of doing this, but I can't use backend).

This is how the I handle the images for example:

```
<img src="{base + '/' + tour.src[0]}" />
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `base` is imported from `$app/paths`? What does `base + '/' + tour.src[0]` evaluate to?

Comment: @PeppeL-G yes I import `base` from `$app/paths`. I should have clarified the tour is an array consisting of different properties, like the name of the tour, price and at last the name of the images. `src` is an array within that array, for example it has these values stored: `['tbilisi-1.webp', 'tbilisi-2.webp', 'tbilisi-3.webp']`. So by writing `base + '\' + tour.src[0]`, I'm basically providing the link to the image.